# Python: Multiple for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

So i want loop the subnet and network at the same time, but i don't know about loop that much

is it posible to do multiple loop?.

I tried to search it but i still confused how it works

and search for loop inside print() and i dont know how it works too

Here's the code

```
mask = "11000000"
subnet = mask.count("1")
subnetl = 2**(subnet)
network = 0+65

for i in range(1,subnetl+1):
    for x in range(network+65):
        print("Subnet",i,"network: ",network)
```

My output

```
Subnet 1 network:  0(x65)
Subnet 2 network:  0(x65)
Subnet 3 network:  0(x65)
Subnet 4 network:  0(x65)
```

Desired output

```
Subnet 1 network:  0
Subnet 2 network:  65
Subnet 3 network:  130
Subnet 4 network:  195
```

Comment: why are you printing `network`? Shouldn't you be printing `i * x`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
mask = "11000000"
subnet = mask.count("1")
subnetl = 2**(subnet)
network = 65

for i in range(0,subnetl):
        print("Subnet",i+1,"network: ",i*network)
```